# Enable min/max button on parts of RCP app

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I created a RCP app following "New Plug-in Project" wizard. (Check "This plug-in will make contributions to the UI" and "Yes". Select template "Eclipse 4 RCP application". Check "Create sample content".) When I run the app, there are no min/max button on the part. I have tried to add them by this CSS:

```
.MPartStack {
  swt-minimize-visible: true;
  swt-maximize-visible: true;
}
```

The buttons appeared but they didn't work. Can you help me to show those buttons correctly? Thanks!

I'm using Eclipse PDE Oxygen Release (4.7.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon` in the 'Add-ons' list in your Application.e4xmi. The full text for the Add-on entry will be:

```
bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon
```

Comment: I cannot add because I can't find this class. Which plugin this class belong to? I just see that I can add `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt` plugin in the manifest dependencies. If I add this plugin. When run the app, an exception throw: `org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
 ...`

Comment: Added the full 'bundleclass' entry as it should appear in the Add-on. This works for me.